# Find difference in two files

Tags: shell

I have two files like below:
file1.txt

```
a 2019 15
b 2019 20
```

file2.txt

```
a 2020 10
b 2019 15
```

Desired output
contents of file1.txt  & diff bw third columns( from file1 & file2) With respect to first column from file 1)

```
  a 2019 5
  b 2019 5
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that the 2nd column for "a" is different?

Comment: oh yeah, wrt column 1 i need to do diff

Comment: You can use `diff` or `vimdiff`

Comment: Can you pls  post the syntax? i am new to learning unix

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "_diff bw third columns_" and I'm a native English speaker. And there's nothing that matches your "_With respect to_" that I can see - or is that a continuation of the preceding text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one-liner to do this.

```bsh
join file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$3-$5}'
```

The `join` command first puts the relevant values on the same line together like this:

```bsh
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/diffy]$ join file{1,2}.txt
a 2019 15 2020 10
b 2019 20 2019 15
```

Then, `awk` prints the first column (`$1`, e.g. `a`), the second column (`$2`, e.g. `2019`), and the value of the 3rd column minus the value in the 5th column (`$3-$5`, e.g. `15 - 10`.)

The result appears to match your desired output:

```
[gnubeard@mothership: ~/diffy]$ join file{1,2}.txt | awk '{print $1,$2,$3-$5}'
a 2019 5
b 2019 5
```

Comment: thanks much. it worked

Comment: Can you help me take percentage of the column 3 ? file 1 third column - file 2 third column divided by file 1 third column * 100

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843831/use-awk-to-calculate-percentage-of-column-1-derived-from-column-2-and-add-it-to) is one such example.